# Why does the wattage on the back of a tube amplifier not match the rating?

Tags: amplifier, watts, vacuum-tube

When I look at the back plate of a 15 watt Fender blues junior amp (which is a tube amplifier, meaning it uses vacuum tubes) it says 150W.

However, the amp is sold as a "15 watt" amp.

Why is there a discrepancy?

[image]

Comment: Because it takes 150W of power to generate 15W of audio power to the speaker on those old Class A tube amps.

Comment: @GTElectronics  That's not an old amp. It's current production.  Guitarist are still, by and large, in love with vacuum tube amplifiers though modelers have come a long way.

Comment: Marco, I think the simplest answer here is that this 150 W is an "allocation" figure. If you have a 15 A circuit branch (beaker) in the US split-phase system this means the entire branch is rated for 1800 W, total. On power-up, this amplifier probably experiences a peak in-rush current as the power supply capacitors charge up, rapidly. They want to rate this so that when you add it to your branch circuit, that you have a reasoned idea about how well it can share the branch. During operation, it's likely much less. This is just a power-up allocation, I think.

Answer (score 6):

The device needs 150 Watts to operate and it can output the 15 Watts to speaker. There is also other circuitry that needs to be run to make an amplifier, such as using power to heat up the tubes.

Which basically means that if you were to constantly output 15 W into speaker, the rest 135 Watts would just be converted to heat.

Comment: I'd bet that a good part of the 15W _electrical_ power that is delivered to the speaker will be converted to heat in the voice coil. Speakers are not 100% efficient. (I don't know the numbers or, what 15W of _acoustic_ energy would sound and/or feel like.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow it all ends up as heat in the end.

Comment: @RoG, Yes, but the fraction that actually was radiated as sound waves does something _useful_ before it becomes heat. The rest is just wasted.

Answer (score 0):

The amp consumes 150 watts and is capable of 15 watts out, 10% efficiency, max.

The Blues Jr. is a Class A amp; which means the 6V6 output tube rests at 100% full on. A signal into the tube drops the current thru the tube in tandem, then it snaps right back to the ceiling with no signal.

That's why class A amps are so inefficient, it consumes the most power when it is sitting idle (on the ceiling) 150 watts consumed and 0 watts out.